# ¿Cómo cambiar la carpeta de almacenamiento de un archivo en ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tengo una aplicación en [expressjs](http://expressjs.com), desde un archivo `.js` subo una imagen, el problema es que no sé como dejar esa imagen en otra carpeta, a continuación muestro el parte del árbol:

```
/bin
/node_modules
/public
--/images
/routes
--images.js
/views
app.js
package.json
```

Desde `images.js` deseo cargar la imagen a `/public/images`

Lo que he intentado es establecer la nueva ruta usando:

```
console.log(app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/../public/images')));
```

Pero el resultado en la consola es:

```
C:\Users\firstname.lastname\Documents\MyApp\routes/../public/data/data.js
```

Comment: `__dirname` ya te la ruta raíz, no habría necesidad de navegar, intenta con `console.log(app.use(express.static( __dirname + 'public/images')));`

Comment: Me parece que no especifiqué bien en la pregunta, `images.js` está dentro de la carpeta `/routes`

Comment: Ok... entonces me parece que será necesario poner `./` para indicar que tome desde la carpeta raíz: `console.log(app.use(express.static( __dirname + './public/images')));`

Comment: utiliza fileSystem  `fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, callback)`

Comment: @Phi muchas gracias, ya publiqué la solución abajo.

Comment: @elporfirio buena idea, la usé pero aún quedaba demasiado rígido, ya encontré la solución y la publiqué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente llegué a la solución con [Path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path) `path.parse(__dirname)`,

```
var iDir = path.parse(__dirname);
console.log(iDir)
/*
{
    "root": "C:\\",
    "dir": "C:\\Users\\firstname.lastname\\Documents\\MyApp",
    "base": "routes",
    "ext": "",
    "name": "routes"
}
*/
var nDir = iDir.dir+'\\public\\images'
console.log(nDir)
// C:\Users\firstname.lastname\Documents\MyApp\public\images
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! ;) +1

Comment: que pasa cuando no es un windows ?

Comment: @elporfirio según el mismo [link](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path)
`path.parse('/home/user/dir/file.txt');`